# I need to open a Pdf file when card view button clicked and each card has its own pdf against

Tags: android, android-volley, androidpdfviewer

Here is my Orderofday.java where i am getting data from URL and in String proceeding_file i get pdf link. i have shown the data present on every card but could not achieve to open a pdf link on card button clicked.

```
public class Orderofday extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = Orderofday.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private OrderList mAdapter;

    ProgressDialog progess;

    List<OrdersModel> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_orderofday);
        progess = new ProgressDialog(Orderofday.this);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mAdapter = new OrderList(myList, Orderofday.this);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        getResult();
    }

    public void getResult() {
        String url = "http://senate.gov.pk/ne/getdata/order_of_day_json.php";

        //detect internet and show the data
        if (isNetworkStatusAvialable(getApplicationContext())) {
            progess.setMessage("Loading data....");
            progess.show();
            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("response", response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject mainList = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray result = mainList.getJSONArray("data");
                        if (result.length() > 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                                mainList = result.getJSONObject(i);
                                OrdersModel model = new OrdersModel();
                                model.title_en = mainList.getString("title_en");
                                model.YearID = mainList.getString("YearID");
                                model.session_title_en = mainList.getString("session_title_en");
                                model.sitting_date = mainList.getString("sitting_date");
                                model.proceeding_file = mainList.getString("proceeding_file");
                                myList.add(model);
                            }
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            progess.dismiss();
                        } else {
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    progess.dismiss();
                }
            });
            Log.d("params", strReq.getUrl() + " and " + strReq.getBodyContentType() + " abd " + strReq.getBodyContentType());
            // Adding String request to request queue
            AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, TAG);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //check internet connection
    public static boolean isNetworkStatusAvialable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo netInfos = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfos != null) {
                return netInfos.isConnected();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my OrderList.java class where i am setting the text from OderModel.java

```
public class OrderList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderList.MyViewHolder> {

    List<OrdersModel> list;
    Context c;

    public OrderList(List<OrdersModel> list, Context c) {

        this.list = list;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.orders_list, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        OrdersModel movie = list.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(movie.gettitle_en());
        holder.type.setText(movie.getYearID());
        holder.session_title.setText((movie.getsession_title_en()));
        holder.sitting_date.setText(movie.getsitting_date());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name, type , session_title , sitting_date , proceeding_file;
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            type = view.findViewById(R.id.type);
            session_title = view.findViewById(R.id.session_title);
            sitting_date = view.findViewById(R.id.sitting_date);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my OrderModel.java where i made getters and setter

```
public class OrdersModel {

    String title_en;
    String YearID;
    String session_title_en;
    String sitting_date;
    String proceeding_file;


    public String gettitle_en() {
        return title_en;
    }
    public void settitle_en(String title_en) {
        this.title_en = title_en;
    }


    public String getYearID() {
        return YearID;
    }
    public void setYearID(String YearID) {
        this.YearID = YearID;
    }


    public String getsession_title_en() {
        return session_title_en;
    }
    public void setsession_title_en(String session_title_en) {
        this.session_title_en = session_title_en;
    }


    public String getsitting_date() {
        return sitting_date;
    }
    public void setsitting_date(String session) {
        this.sitting_date = sitting_date;
    }


    public String getproceeding_file() {
        return proceeding_file;
    }
    public void setproceeding_file(String date) {
        this.proceeding_file = proceeding_file;
    }

    String file;
}
```

Now i need to open a pdf against every card view clicked i got url of pdf in procedding_file (String) but couldn't get it. Kindly help me out to achieve this and here is xml.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Title_ID"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="YearID"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/session_title"
            android:layout_below="@id/type"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Session Title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sitting_date"
            android:layout_below="@id/session_title"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Date "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/view_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sitting_date"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Click to View Pdf"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp">
        </Button>

        <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:id="@+id/pdfView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `viewButton` in ViewHolder.

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView name, type , session_title , sitting_date , proceeding_file;
    public Button viewButton;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        type = view.findViewById(R.id.type);
        session_title = view.findViewById(R.id.session_title);
        sitting_date = view.findViewById(R.id.sitting_date);
        viewButton = view.findViewById(R.id.view_button);
    }
}
```

Then set `onClickListener` on `viewButton` and openPdf

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    OrdersModel movie = list.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(movie.gettitle_en());
    holder.type.setText(movie.getYearID());
    holder.session_title.setText((movie.getsession_title_en()));
    holder.sitting_date.setText(movie.getsitting_date());

    holder.viewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openPdf(movie.getproceeding_file())
        }
    });
}
```

**Suggestion:** You should move your `PdfViewer` in another activity and redirect user to that activity when click `viewButton`.

Comment: where is openPdf() method ?

Comment: You have to implement it according your requirements? What are you trying to do? you put PdfViewer inside listitem. How can you show pdf within this tiny space? Check my suggestion

Comment: Also I suggest you to use **shxdos** pdfviewer as it's support pdf from `URL`. Check: https://jitpack.io/p/shxdos/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: i have a webview on this activity when the button is clicked it will navigate to webview to open pdf

Comment: Is it same activity or different? Post that part also

Comment: it is the same activity orderofday and i have a webview in orderofday xml that is posted above

Comment: kindly post a openPdf() method to open a pdf on webview and id of webview is @pdfView

Comment: `orderlist.java` is an adapter, it contains RecyclerView items. How can you show PDF in this tiny space?

Comment: in RecyclerView items each item contain a pdf when an item is clicked it should open a pdf in webview. now you suggest me what to do im very worried :(

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct. However a better solution and the rightest one is to create an interface  for the clicklistenet and implement it in tour activity

Answer (score 0):

1. initialise view_pdf button in MyViewHolder class. like others.
2. parse proceeding file like others  ~ movie.getproceeding_file()
3. under the onBindViewHolder put below snippet of code:

   ```
     holder.proceeding_file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

           String pdf_url = movie.getproceeding_file();
           // do not forget to concate preceding url of the pdf
           Webview webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
           webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           webView.loadUrl(pdf_url);

         }
      });
   ```